# How To Draw Edge Weighted Network Graph

Tags: matlab

So Assume that I have a table like this:

```
    Source     target         interval         weight
  192.168.2.101 192.168.2.102   0.691597938537598   0.54
  192.168.2.101 192.168.2.109   0.691597938537598   0.44
  192.168.2.101 192.168.2.106   0.691597938537598   0
  192.168.2.101 192.168.2.105   0.691597938537598   0.12
```

How can I draw a network graph with Source and Target as the table, and edges weighted (thickness that is) as per the weight column?

Also, as seen from the example, the weight between a certain pair may change with time, any way to show that? Thanks.

Comment: If you want *only* the picture/animated figure, then you should try TeX/LaTeX. Look around at the sister site [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I want to do it with Matlab's Graph functions

Comment: What have you tried? We are not going to create a function for you, I hope you were not expecting that!

Comment: You could easily do this with [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io)'s [drawing](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html) API.